# HTML5 video slider - Creating elements on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm creating a custom HTML5 (full-width) video slider. Everything is going fine so far, but I'm wondering what's the quickest way to load video's.

Currently my approach is to create `<video>` elements on the fly. So when the next slide is loaded, the video element is created. I attached an eventlistener to the video to make sure to play it when it's loaded properly.

```
/**
 * Load and create the video on the fly
 */
var loadVideo = function(slide) {
    var video = $('<video muted></video>'),
        source = $('<source src="' + slide.attr('data-video') + '" type="video/mp4">');

    video.html(source);

    video.on('click', function() {
        var video = $(this)[0];
        if(video.playing) {
            video.pause();
        } else {
            video.play();
        }
    });

    video[0].addEventListener('canplay', showVideo(video), false);
    video[0].addEventListener('ended', hideVideo(video), false);

    // Append the newly created video element with it's source to the slide
    slide.html(video);
};
```

This works pretty good, and I think it's faster then loading 3/4/5 video's all at once when the DOM is rendered. Is this true? And would you have any tips/suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: sounds good to me, rather wait on one than many, plus less data used for mobile. unless there is some library out there...